# illegal start of expression error but i have all my curly braces

Tags: java, curly-braces

```
public String starOut(String str) {
  int i = 0;
  while(i <= str.length()-2){
    if(str.substring(i, i+1).equals(*) && i < 2){
      str = str.substring(i+2);
    }
    else if(str.substring(i, i+1).equals("*")){
      str = str.substring(i-2, i-1)+ str.substring(i+2); 
    }
    i++
  }
  return str;
}
```

I get an error saying "missing '}' or illegal start of expression" but I have all of the curly braces I think. Help!

Comment: *.equals(\*)* what does this mean? probably you miss the double quotes

Answer (score 2):

You forgot double quotes around "*" (Line 3) and semicolon after i++ (Line 9).

```
public String starOut(String str) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= str.length()-2) {
        if(str.substring(i, i+1).equals("*") && i < 2) {
            str = str.substring(i+2);
        }
        else if(str.substring(i, i+1).equals("*")) {
            str = str.substring(i-2, i-1)+ str.substring(i+2); 
        }
        i++;
    }
    return str;
  }
```

I also recommend using charAt instead of doing substrings to retrieve characters at particular positions.
So at the end it will look like this:

```
public String starOut(String str) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= str.length() - 2){
        if(str.charAt(i) == '*' && i < 2){
            str = str.substring(i + 2);
        }
        else if(str.charAt(i) == '*'){
            str = str.charAt(i - 2) + str.substring(i + 2);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return str;
}
```